# drag object vertically

Tags: iphone, drag

i like to drag this object vertically instead of horizontally, which is doin it now:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(myObject.frame, location)){
    CGPoint xLocation = CGPointMake(location.x, myObject.center.y);
    myObject.center = xLocation;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CGPoint yLocation = CGPointMake(myObject.center.x, location.y);
myObject.center = yLocation;
```

Comment: ok. but i got still a little problem: draging is workin outside the object with that code:
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    CGPoint xLocation = CGPointMake(location.x, myObject.center.y);
    myObject.center = xLocation;
}

but not with the code above.

Comment: Add this to the question. It's very difficult to read code in comments.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. That's precisely what the `CGRectContainsPoint` test is supposed to do. It suppresses dragging when the touch is outside the object's frame.